# Posts/Images overlapped when clicked on filter options and display in masonry view after window resize

Tags: php, css, ajax, filter, masonry

I've created a filter to display my posts popularity wise, style wise and 
country wise.

Screenshots:

[Screenshot 1: Working fine when page loads it shows all the posts/images properly in masonry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXTVZ.jpg)

[Screenshot 2: When clicking on filter menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSvAj.png)

By default, it shows the posts/images in a masonry grid view.

When I click on popular link/button, it shows the posts popularity-wise.

The problem is when I click on popular link/button, it is showing the posts/images but all of them are overlapped. And when I resize the page/window then it shows the posts/images in masonry view.

Here is the code:

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // init Masonry  
  var $grid = jQuery('#images').masonry({
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.item',
  isFitWidth: true,
  columnWidth: 1
  });

  // layout Masonry after each image loads
  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
  });

  jQuery("span.popularFilter").click(function(){
  var popular = jQuery(this).attr('data-slug');

  jQuery.ajax({
  url : ajaxurl,
  type : 'post',
  data : {
  action : 'post_popular_filter',
  popular_attr : popular
  },
  success : function( response ) {
  jQuery("#images").html(response); 
  $grid.masonry('reloadItems')
  }
  });
  });

});
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

```
function masonaryGrid(){
setTimeout(function(){
$grid.masonry('reloadItems')
$grid.masonry('layout');
},true)
}

// init Masonry  
var $grid = jQuery('#images').masonry({
// options...
itemSelector: '.item',
isFitWidth: true,
columnWidth: 1
});

// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
$grid.masonry('layout');
});

jQuery("span.popularFilter").click(function(){
var popular = jQuery(this).attr('data-slug');

jQuery.ajax({
url : ajaxurl,
type : 'post',
data : {
action : 'post_popular_filter',
popular_attr : popular
},
success : function( response ) {
jQuery("#images").html(response); 
masonaryGrid();
}
});
});
```